# Shell replace forward slashes with backslashes

Tags: shell, text-processing, filenames

I have a question: how to replace forward slashes with backslashes?

I have string:

```
App/Models
```

And I need

```
App\Models
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Where do you have this string? In a file or in a variable? Is it part of some larger piece of data that also has slashes that should _not_ be changed? What shell are you using?

Comment: Have a look at `tr` or `sed`.

Comment: any search on this site or on google would have yielded answers for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (in e.g. `bash`),

```bsh
string="App/Models"
echo "${string//\//\\}"
```

or if you don't have it as variable, you can use `tr`:

```
printf '%s\n' "App/Models" | tr '/' '\'
```

Comment: It's a bit tough to parse out what's happening here among the mess of '\' and '/', it would be helpful to break down the pieces of the substitution, or point to some documentation where we could read about substitutions (I'm finding it a bit hard to find such documentation)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "App/Models" | sed -e 's|/|\\|g'
App\Models
```

Comment: Use `y///` rather than `s///g` to change single characters globally in `sed`, it's much more efficient. In this case, the `tr` utility would have been a better fit though.